# The application gnome-panel has quit unexpectedly

Tags: gnome, crash, gnome-panel

I'm getting the following error on a Solaris machine when logged in via VNC.

```
The application gnome-panel has quit unexpectedly.
```

The two options I see are `Restart Application` and `Close`.

I would highly appreciate if anyone can throw more light on this.

Comment: One suggestion I saw on redhat's bugzilla issue tracker was to let GNOME recreate the dot files in your home directory. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=120014. If you've got nothing else to try this is an option 8-).

Comment: Is this issue resolved then? A reboot is the solution, or are you just stating that you rebooted and it's working again for now?

Comment: @slm: Rebooted and it seems to work for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked upon rebooting the node